# Inequality within "when" statement outputs error

Tags: kotlin, case-when, inequality

Here I have a program which assigns the value of a variable based on different conditions:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
   var age = readLine()!!.toInt()
   var string_age = when(age) {
       in 0..11 -> "Child"
       in 12..17 -> "Teen"
       in 18..64 -> "Adult"
       age > 64 -> "Senior"
       else -> "Invalid age"
   }
   print(string_age)
}
```

However, the inequality "age > 64" returns "incompatible types: Boolean and Int". What must I do in order to use an inequality within a "when" statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't use `when`'s argument in `when`'s cases explicitly.
So you can adjust your code like this:

```kotlin
var string_age = when(age) {
    in 0..11 -> "Child"
    in 12..17 -> "Teen"
    in 18..64 -> "Adult"
    else -> {
        if (age > 64) {
            "Senior"
        } else {
            "Invalid age"
        }
    }
}
```

Or like this, moving `age` out of `when` and using it explicitly in all cases

```kotlin
var string_age = when {
    age in 0..11 -> "Child"
    age in 12..17 -> "Teen"
    age in 18..64 -> "Adult"
    age > 64 -> "Senior";
    else -> "Invalid age"
}
```

Or you can use following trick with range

`in 65..200 -> "Senior"` instead of `age > 64 -> "Senior"`.
200 years is big enough for a person's lifespan ;)

Comment: Thanks so much man; I was so confused on why it wasn't working since it seemed simple. Is it recommended to not use an argument for a when statement?

Comment: @EvanBain it depends on what kind of checks you do. If you have an argument to be analyzed by set of checks (that's your case) and all those checks are similar it's better to use `when(argument)`. For more complex checks and when more than one argument is used it's better to use `when` without argument. Since your case is rather simple i'd recomend to follow my 3rd advice -- `in 65..200 -> "Senior"`. I doubt people can live >200 years :)